# cannot pass variable with url_for flask, python, html5

Tags: python, flask

I was trying to put a link in some text through url_for (flask, python3) and also pass a variable but nothing I tried worked .Here's the code I used. Am I doing something wrong?
html5:

```
<a class="mr-2" href={{ url_for('user','username'=posts.author)}} >TEXT</a>
```

python3:

```
@app.route('/user')
def user(username):
    print(username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to change the template code to look like:

```
<a class="mr-2" href="{{ url_for('user',username=posts.author) }}" >TEXT</a>
```

However you'd also have to change the python code for this to be valid:

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def user(username):
    print(username)
```

A valid request is now:

```
/user/CodEdo
```

Which is the URL which should be rendered in the `href` assuming that `posts.author` in the template is `CodEdo`.